# Can GC Application be linked to an ARC Framework?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, garbage-collection, automatic-ref-counting

I have an application that uses GC for memory management and a framework that does automatic reference counting. When I try to build that, I get this error:

```
Linked dylibs built for retain/release but object files built for GC-only for architecture x86_64
```

Is there a correct way to use the ARC framework in this GC application without changing it? I remember to read that ARC code seemslessly works with non-ARC code, but I only find the per-file compiler switch (`-fobjc-arc`).

Comment: The framework and the application are in separate projects, hold together by a workspace.

Answer (score 1):

No. ARC code works with manual retain-release code, but not with GC code. A framework built for garbage collection only will not work with either manual retain-release code or ARC; a framework built in GC-optional mode will work the same with both.

Comment: Why is that? I can generally use any Framework with GC, mostly of which are manually memory-managed. And ARC is explained as letting the compiler automatically do what ones does as manual memory management otherwise.

Comment: You’re mistaken. GC and manual RR code can’t be used together.

Comment: It is possible and quite widely practiced to have manually memory-managed frameworks "support" GC. I just looked that up. That's what I was referring to in the comment by saying "I can generally use any". That was admittedly too broad. All of Apple's preinstalled frameworks seem to work that way, though, and many mainstream open source ones as well. So in that sense I'm not mistaken, do you agree?

Comment: It’s possible to build a “dual-mode” framework that works with both GC and RR code, and you can use ARC in RR mode to do it, but this is not the same as an unmodified _GC-only_ framework as per the question. (Answer amended for clarification.)

Comment: As per what the question is, please reread it. This question was a poor experience. Have a good day.

Comment: I got the memory modes of the framework and app backwards, but the answer – given that the question contains “without changing it” – remains “no”; if you remove that condition, ARC is not in any way an impediment.